# Drawing a perpendicular bisector on pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a perpendicular bisector through the line segment with endpoints $P = (1,-1)$ and $Q = (3,-6)$.  (The domain is twice the length of the range.)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=3.25in, height=3.25in, clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-5,xmax=15,
    ymin=-7,ymax=3,
    restrict y to domain=-7:3,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    axis line style={shorten >=-12.5pt, shorten <=-12.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, xshift=12.5pt, anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, yshift=12.5pt, anchor=south west}
]


%The equation for the line through P and Q is (-5/2)*x + 3/2, and the equation for line $\ell$
%that is the perpendicular bisector for PQ is y = (2/5)x - 43/10.  The x-intercept for $\ell$
%is (43/4, 0).

\addplot[latex-latex, dashed, domain=-17/4:15] {(2/5)*x - 43/10};
\addplot[domain=1:3] {(-5/2)*x + 3/2};

\draw[fill] (1,-1) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw[fill] (3,-6) circle [radius=1.5pt];

\coordinate (label_for_ell) at (15,17/10);

\coordinate (label_for_P) at (1,-1);
\coordinate (label_for_Q) at (3,-6);

\end{axis}

\draw node[anchor={atan(2/5)+180}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(label_for_ell) +({atan(2/5)}:0.15)$){$\ell$};

\draw node[anchor={atan(-5/2)-90}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(label_for_P) +({atan(-5/2)+90}:0.15)$){$P$};
\draw node[anchor={atan(-5/2)-90}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(label_for_Q) +({atan(-5/2)+90}:0.15)$){$Q$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `axis equal=true` or `(axis cs: 1,-1)`?

Comment: @John Kormylo  What does `axis equal=true` instruct `pgfplots` to do?  Isn't `(1,-1)` plotted correctly on the Cartesian plane?

Comment: @John Kormylo  I changed the width and height to `width=4in` and `height=2in`.  It looks fine, now.

Comment: If you want the perpendicular to actually look perpendicular, you need the x and y axes to have the same scale.  `axis equal=true` does that (pgfplots treats the width and height more as suggestions than orders).  To draw the perpendicular bisector you can either derive the formula and use pgfplots, or use the tikz calc library.  One should always use (axis cs: x,y) with tikz commands.

Comment: @John Kormylo  I appreciate all the tips.  I did not know that `pgfplots` had flexibility in rendering the values for `width=4in` and `height=2in`.  I will put `axis equal=true` in the `axis` environment.

Comment: @John Kormylo  Are you saying that I should replace the commands that I have in my post for locating `P` and `Q` with `\coordinate (label_for_P) at (axis cs: 1,-1);`
`\coordinate (label_for_Q) at (axis cs: 3,-6);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What John is saying is that when in using PGFplots there are a lot of scaling going on, so PGFplots makes available several extra coordinate systems. There is the `axis cs` which represents the axis values, say your dealing with a log plot, then `(axis cs:10000,100)` is not actually `(10000cm,100cm)` that would be if `axis cs:` was ommited and the default values for `x` and `y` keys are being used.

There's also the `axis description cs` which correspond to the axis box and is given in 0 to 1 scale. To exemplify, `(axis description cs:0,0)` is the bottom left corner of the axis box and `(axis description cs:1,1)` the top right corner. There are even others useful coordinate systems, all this information is available in much more detail [in the PGFplots manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf).

So that's why inside an `axis` you normally don't want to use the natural coordiinate system because of the scaling.

Still, in my opinion as the plot/drawing is now, PGFplots is overkill. Ti*k*Z can handle it easily enough, so below there's a pure Ti*k*Z MWE and your MWE with the appropriate changes (`axis equal=true` and there was also and extra `shorten` that was throwing the arrows off the bounding box).

## MWE (Ti*k*Z)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    >=latex, axis/.style={<->},
    point/.style={circle, inner sep=0pt, fill, minimum size=4pt, label=#1},
    scale=.75]
\draw[axis] (0,-7) -- (0,3) node[above right]{$y$};
\draw[axis] (-5,0) -- (15,0) node[below right]{$x$};
\node[point=$P$] (P) at (1,-5/2 + 3/2) {};
\node[point=$Q$] (Q) at (3,-5*3/2 + 3/2) {};
\draw (P) -- (Q);
\draw[<->,dashed] (-17/4,{(2/5)*(-17/4) - 43/10}) -- (15,15*2/5 - 43/10) node[above]{$\ell$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## MWE (PGFplots)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=3.25in, height=3.25in, clip=false, axis equal=true,
        axis lines=middle,
        xmin=-5,xmax=15,
        ymin=-7,ymax=3,
        restrict y to domain=-7:3,
        axis line style={latex-latex},
        xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
        xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
        axis line style={shorten >=-12.5pt},
        xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, xshift=12.5pt, anchor=north west},
        ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, yshift=12.5pt, anchor=south west}
    ]
      %The equation for the line through P and Q is (-5/2)*x + 3/2, and the equation for line $\ell$
      %that is the perpendicular bisector for PQ is y = (2/5)x - 43/10.  The x-intercept for $\ell$
      %is (43/4, 0).

      \addplot[latex-latex, dashed, domain=-17/4:15] {(2/5)*x - 43/10};
      \addplot[domain=1:3] {(-5/2)*x + 3/2};

      \draw[fill] (axis cs:1,-1) circle [radius=1.5pt];
      \draw[fill] (axis cs:3,-6) circle [radius=1.5pt];

      \coordinate (label_for_ell) at (axis cs:15,17/10);

      \coordinate (label_for_P) at (axis cs:1,-1);
      \coordinate (label_for_Q) at (axis cs:3,-6);
    \end{axis}

    \draw node[anchor={atan(2/5)+180}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(label_for_ell) +({atan(2/5)}:0.15)$){$\ell$};
    \draw node[anchor={atan(-5/2)-90}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(label_for_P) +({atan(-5/2)+90}:0.15)$){$P$};
    \draw node[anchor={atan(-5/2)-90}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(label_for_Q) +({atan(-5/2)+90}:0.15)$){$Q$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I did not know that in an `axis` environment there is scaling that is unspecified by the code.  Using `axis cs:` within the parentheses in which the coordinates of a point are specified prevents that.

Comment: I appreciate you including the code for the same drawing that avoids `pgfplots`.

Comment: Don't get this the wrong way but the scaling may not be *specified* but it ***is wanted***, pretty much always. And whenever you specify `width` and/or `height` you'll also be most likely demanding scaling too. I recommend, if you have the time, to dive a little in the manuals (specially for tikz) they're quite interesting!

Comment: From 1.11 (I think) on, the default coordinate system is axis cs so you can skip writing it.

Comment: @percusse, funny, I was getting bad results without the `axis cs`, must have been some other setting because now it works fine with or without it. Thank's for the info.

Comment: It's probably you didn't include the `compat` setting. Then it falls back to old behavior